# CSS for banner element layout, to respect text content, maximum height and aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, aspect-ratio

I am trying to build out a banner element on a website, and am having an issue getting it to fulfil the criteria I am after. Ideally I would like to have a solution that is CSS only.

The layout is pretty simple - a background image, with centered text overlaid. Diagram below:

[image]

In order of priority, I need the element to do the following:

1. The element must always be tall enough to accomodate the text within it. This comes from a CMS so could be of any length.
2. As long as it does not break the first criteria, the element must not be taller than 80svh
3. As long as it does not break the first and second criteria, the element must respect the aspect ratio of the background image. Again, this is from a CMS, so I have the image width and height available to me to use in any `aspect-ratio` CSS.

My first attempt looked like this:

```css
div.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

div.image-holder {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 80svh;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  position: relative;
}

div.text-holder {
  padding: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 30;
}

p {
  max-width: 760px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 2.3rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image-holder">
    <img src="https://placebear.com/1200/800" alt="Bears" />
  </div>
  <div class="text-holder">
    <p>Central text element, amount of text unknown. Solution must work for any amount of added text.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This fulfilled criteria 1, but as long as the element was large enough to accomodate the text the overall height was always set to 80svh, and didn't do anything with the aspect ratio of the image.

Then I tried the following:

```css
div.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

div.image-holder {
  width: 100%;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  position: relative;
}

div.text-holder {
  padding: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 30;
}

p {
  max-width: 760px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 2.3rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image-holder">
    <img src="https://placebear.com/1200/800" alt="Bears" />
  </div>
  <div class="text-holder" style="aspect-ratio: 1200 / 800; // This is inlined as it is pulled from the image size from the CMS">
    <p>Central text element, amount of text unknown. Solution must work for any amount of added text.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This was closer, and fulfilled criteria 1 and 3, but now I didn't have the max height of the element set to 80svh. So the element would carry on scaling at the aspect ratio to any height.

I am stuck as to what to try next. I am hoping this isn't an unusual layout aim, and that someone has managed this before. If I need to lean on javascript for this I will, but I am hoping to get it done with CSS if possible.

Comment: object-fit: cover; comes with object-position too to let you decide which side(s) are to be clipped

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I am aware of the object-position property, but am not sure of the relevance of it in this instance?

Comment: I'm not too sure myself of your expectation: if you want either to keep the ratio of any image with a min-height of about 80vh, and/or also  fitting in a viewport that can have any ratio (screensize, portrait or landscape view, browser window resized, ... there is choice to make : cover and clip or shrink the element to the ratio of the image itself, so it stands within the min-height or the space needed by the text)

Comment: Ok - yes so perhaps what I want can't be done. I will keep experimenting and see if I can sort something out. Will open it up for a bounty tomorrow see if anything comes of it.

Comment: Side note: All else aside, this kind of statement "must respect the aspect ratio of the background image" always annoys me (have seen it elsewhere). Why? Why must a background image aspect ratio be respected? I think most of the time it should be the other way around: a background image, because it's a _filler decoration_, should respect the aspect ratio of the containment. The only time you see the opposite of this is when the actual image is the primary subject matter: a photo gallery, or a photo placed in an article. In these cases, it's no longer a background image.

Comment: Sorry for causing offence, and thanks for your comment. In this instance the images are of importance, as they are part of a website for a studio. And while I appreciate that the image is, in this case, a background to some text, I don't think it is unreasonable to want the image not to be cropped from its original composition if possible. Assuming of course that it is fulfilling its primary function of providing a background first.

Comment: Bit of an aside, but requirements 1 & 2 are mutually oppositional, fighting each other. Is this your own interpretation of the requirements or someone else's? If the requirements exist in text form and this isn't a direct copy and paste of them, please share the original (or as close as is safe). If it's being translated to English it would be good to include it in the original language because automatic translation is not always great.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we're allowed to change the HTML structure, we can add `max-height: 100%` to the container of both text and image holder (in this example I used `both-holder`), then also add `max-height: 80svh` to the main `wrapper`:

```css
div.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr));
  max-height: 80svh;
}

div.image-holder {
  z-index: 5;
}

div.both-holder {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.text-holder {
  z-index: 30;
  padding: 2rem;
}

p {
  max-width: 760px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 2.3rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="both-holder" style="aspect-ratio: 1200 / 800; // This is inlined as it is pulled from the image size from the CMS">
    <div class="image-holder">
      <img src="https://placebear.com/1200/800" alt="Bears" />
    </div>
    <div class="text-holder">
      <p>Central text element, amount of text unknown. Solution must work for any amount of added text.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have changed your last example and set a max value of 80svh fro the grid row.
I should work now

```css
div.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(0, 80svh);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

div.image-holder {
  width: 100%;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  position: relative;
}

div.text-holder {
  padding: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 30;
}

p {
  max-width: 760px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 2.3rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image-holder">
    <img src="https://placebear.com/1200/800" alt="Bears" />
  </div>
  <div class="text-holder">
    <p>Central text element, amount of text unknown. Solution must work for any amount of added text.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This violates points 1 and 3. If you add more text, you will see for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use the `padding-bottom` trick to maintain the aspect ratio for the image-holder. The `max-height` property ensures that the banner won't exceed 80svh.

```css
div.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr));
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 80svh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.image-holder {
  width: 100%;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: calc(100% / (1200 / 800));
}

div.text-holder {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 30;
}

p {
  max-width: 760px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 2.3rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image-holder">
    <img src="https://placebear.com/1200/800" alt="Bears" />
  </div>
  <div class="text-holder">
    <p>Central text element, amount of text unknown. Solution must work for any amount of added text.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

In your case, you need to add some tricks. For example, first image will serve for the `aspect-ratio`, and last image that will have `position: absolute;` relative to `.wrapper` in case the height of `.image-holder` is too small or big.
For example, something like this:

```css
body{
  min-width: 320px;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'a';
  position: relative;
  --max-img-height: 80svh;
}

.image-holder {
  grid-area: a;
  height: fit-content(var(--max-img-height));
  display: grid;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.image-holder img {
  width: 100%;
}

.image-holder img:first-child {
  max-height: var(--max-img-height);
}

.image-holder img:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.text-holder {
  padding: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  grid-area: a;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.text-holder p {
  max-width: 760px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 2.3rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image-holder">
    <img src="https://placebear.com/1200/800" alt="Bears">
    <img src="https://placebear.com/1200/800" alt="Bears">
  </div>
  <div class="text-holder">
    <p>Central text element, amount of text unknown. Solution must work for any amount of added text. Central text element, amount of text unknown.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution does not meet the criterion of maintaining the image aspect ratio. Particularly visible on narrow viewports, the image has a fixed height of 80vh rather than shrinking to maintain its intrinsic aspect ratio.

Comment: @BrettDonald Yes you're right. Thank you. I've updated my answer, seems to work properly now.

Answer (score -2):

```css
body {
  min-width: 320px;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'a';
  position: relative;
  --max-img-height: 80vh;
}

.image-holder {
  grid-area: a;
  min-height: 100%; /* Ensure it's tall enough to accommodate the text */
  max-height: var(--max-img-height); /* Not taller than 80vh */
  display: grid;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.image-holder img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover; /* Maintain aspect ratio and cover the container */
}

.text-holder {
  padding: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  grid-area: a;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.text-holder p {
  max-width: 760px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 2.3rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image-holder">
    <img src="https://placebear.com/1200/800" alt="Bears">
    <img src="https://placebear.com/1200/800" alt="Bears">
  </div>
  <div class="text-holder">
    <p>Central text element, amount of text unknown. Solution must work for any amount of added text. Central text element, amount of text unknown.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You copied my answer, and added a bit delusional. First, `min-height` has priority over `max-height`. Second, when you hard set the width and height for the image (and they don't match the dimensions of the image), it won't preserve the aspect ratio.